# Lazy Loading issue while overriding UserClaimsPrincipalFactory in IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have an empty claim while trying to add the ApplicationUser property as a claim in identity.
Looks like ef have an issue with the lazy loading of the two following properties.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser Manager { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ApplicationUser> ManagerOf { get; set; }
}
```

I know that I'm entering in this piece of code.
But inside GenerateClaimsAsync, The user has its property set to null ( only the two above ). And I checked in Database, I have the values well defined.

```
public class MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        var managerId = "";
        if (user.Manager?.Id != null)
        {
            managerId = user.Manager.Id;
        }
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("manager_id", managerId));
        var managerOf = "";
        if (user.ManagerOf != null)
        {
            managerOf = string.Join(", ", user.ManagerOf.Select(u => u.Id).ToArray());     
        }

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("manager_of", managerOf));
        return identity;
    }
}
```

Do you guys have an idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: I guess the first question is - have you explicitly enabled lazy loading on the DbContext? If you enable debug logging for EF do you see any log or debug messages when stepping through that code?

Comment: Any *lazy* property must be accessed from within the scope of `DbContext`, even to create a DTO of a different type

Comment: @mackie Nope, I thought it was the default behavior in dotnet core. I'll try it

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ what do you mean by the "scope" of dbcontext ? Which scope qre we talking about ?

Comment: you must be under the (`using (DbContext dbContext = new DbContext()){...}`) curly braces

Comment: @mackie The problem was that lazy loading is not enabled by default as I thought. I found this tutorial which helps me: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/lazy-loading. And my problem is solved now :)

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ in a web app the DbContext will typically be scoped to the request so while I'm not a huge fan of lazy loading it's fine it assume that the DbContext is "alive" in this context.

Comment: @Astyan good to know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mackie pointed out, lazy loading is not enabled by default.
I only needed to enable the lazy loading by following this tutorial: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/lazy-loading.